# Request: "ignored" tags don't belong in sidebar

Tags: feature-request

I have a good couple hundred "ignored" tags, and add more every day. The list is so large, that I can't get to the pagination controls without scrolling down about 8 feet, which is especially annoying given that on any pageful I only see 2 or 3 questions. My solution is to entirely remove the sidebar (using Firefox [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108)), since the different modules don't have ids to grab. This makes navigation a breeze, but also makes it inconvenient to add new tags to the ignore list, since I have to unhide the whole monster, scroll down to the entry box, and hide everything again).

The sidebar is valuable real estate, and there's no use case for seeing the ignore tags there. Can you remove them from the sidebar, and have a special page for (the rare case of) deleting them?

For interested others, here's my Stylish script for SO:

EDIT: Much more refined script! This is my ideal SO interface:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  #sidebar > * { display: none }
  #sidebar > :nth-child(5) { display: inherit }
  #sidebar > :nth-child(5) > * { display: none }
  #sidebar > :nth-child(5) > :nth-child(4) { display: inherit }
  #sidebar > :nth-child(5) > :nth-child(6) { display: inherit }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your interests are so narrow, why not just browse by tag?

You can combine tags like so:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

Comment: My interests aren't particularly narrow, I don't think. Because people tag poorly, I get better accuracy by filtering out. Filtering "in" would give poor recall--I'd miss many interesting questions, whereas I know I don't know anything about, say, "qmake", or "c++-builder-2007".

Comment: I'm with Jeff on this one. You can benefit a lot from looking at questions you don't know anything about. By definition, if you know nothing about it, then a question on that topic will teach you something you didn't know. Are you allergic to learning or something, Jonathan?

Comment: Why do I want to "learn something" from someone who doesn't know anything about something that I don't care about? Or are you a troll?

Comment: OK, you might be a troll, but you're damned funny, and your web site image trick is one of the most beautiful css hacks I've ever seen, so... troll away!

Comment: It's not a hack, it's **magic**.

Answer (score 1):

You have an option called `Hide Ignored Tags` at https://stackoverflow.com/users/143938?tab=preferences#sort-top.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
div#ignoredTags {
    display: none;
}
```

...?